# Working out how many days old a person is?

Tags: javascript

I need to work out how many days old someone is, but I'm not sure on the math. Here's what I have so far:

```
var birthYear = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your birth year:'));
var birthMonth = prompt ('Enter the name of the month of birth:');
var birthDay = parseInt(prompt ('Enter your day of birth as an integer:'));
var milliDay = 1000*60*60*24; //Milliseconds in a day
monthAbb = 'janfebmaraprmayjunjulaugsepoctnovdec';
chineseZod = 12;
zodCycle = 1924; //Chinese Zodiac Cycle
var zodAnimal = new Array('Rat','Ox','Tiger','Rabbit','Dragon','Snake','Horse','Goat','Monkey','Rooster','Dog','Pig');
var zodAnimalD = new Array('Forthright, tenacious, intense, meticulous, charismatic, sensitive, intellectual, industrious, charming, eloquent, sociable, artistic, and shrewd.  Can be manipulative, vindictive, self-destructive, envious, mendacious, venal, obstinate, critical, over-ambitious, ruthless, intolerant, and scheming.','Dependable, ambitious, calm, methodical, born leader, patient, hardworking, conventional, steady, modest, logical, resolute, and tenacious.  Can be stubborn, dogmatic, hot-tempered, narrow-minded, materialistic, rigid, and demanding.','Unpredictable, rebellious, colorful, powerful, passionate, daring, impulsive, vigorous, stimulating, sincere, affectionate, humanitarian, and generous.  Can be restless, reckless, impatient, quick-tempered, obstinate, selfish, aggressive, and moody.','Gracious, good friend, kind, sensitive, soft-spoken, amiable, elegant, reserved, cautious, artistic, thorough, tender, self-assured, shy, astute, compassionate, lucky, and flexible.  Can be moody, detached, superficial, self-indulgent, opportunistic, and stubborn.','Magnanimous, stately, vigorous, strong, self-assured, proud, noble, direct, dignified, eccentric, intellectual, fiery, passionate, decisive, pioneering, artistic, generous, and loyal.  Can be tactless, arrogant, imperious, tyrannical, demanding, intolerant, dogmatic, violent, impetuous, and brash.','Deep thinker, wise, mystic, graceful, soft-spoken, sensual, creative, prudent, shrewd, elegant, cautious, responsible, calm, strong, constant, and purposeful.  Can be a loner, bad communicator, possessive, hedonistic, self-doubting, distrustful, mendacious, suffocating, and cold.','Cheerful, popular, quick-witted, changeable, earthy, perceptive, talkative, agile, magnetic, intelligent, astute, flexible, and open-minded.  Can be fickle, arrogant, childish, anxious, rude, gullible, and stubborn.','Righteous, sincere, sympathetic, mild-mannered, observant, artistic, intellectual, ingenious, innovative, creative, mothering, peaceful, and generous.  Can be indecisive, over-passive, worrier, pessimistic, sensitive, shy, and weak-willed.','Inventor, motivator, improviser, quick-witted, inquisitive, flexible, innovative, problem solver, self-assured, sociable, artistic, polite, dignified, competitive, objective, and factual.  Can be egotistical, vain, arrogant, selfish, reckless, snobbish, deceptive, manipulative, cunning, jealous, suspicious, and stubborn.','  Acute, neat, meticulous, organized, self-assured, decisive, conservative, critical, perfectionist, alert, zealous, practical, scientific, and responsible.  Can be over zealous and critical, puritanical, egotistical, abrasive, proud, opinionated, and gives into empty bravado.','Honest, intelligent, straightforward, loyal, sense of justice and fair play, attractive, amicable, unpretentious, sociable, open-minded, idealistic, moralistic, practical, affectionate, sensitive, and easy going.  Can be cynical, lazy, cold, judgmental, pessimistic, worrier, stubborn, and quarrelsome.','Honest, gallant, sturdy, sociable, peace-loving, patient, loyal, hard-working, trusting, sincere, calm, understanding, thoughtful, scrupulous, passionate, and intelligent.  Can be naive, over-reliant, self-indulgent, gullible, fatalistic, and materialistic.');
var monthArr = new Array(11);

monthArr [0] = "jan";
monthArr [1] = "feb";
monthArr [2] = "mar";
monthArr [3] = "apr";
monthArr [4] = "may";
monthArr [5] = "jun";
monthArr [6] = "jul";
monthArr [7] = "aug";
monthArr [8] = "sep";
monthArr [9] = "oct";
monthArr [10] = "nov";
monthArr [11] = "dec";

var monthNum = monthAbb.indexOf(birthMonth.slice(0, 3).toLowerCase()) / 3; 
alert(monthNum);
var d = new Date (birthYear, monthNum, birthDay);
alert(d);
var dCurrent = new Date();
dCurrent = dCurrent.getTime(); //Grabs the time of the current date in milliseconds.
var dTotal = dCurrent - d;
alert(dTotal);
dTotal = dTotal / milliDay;
dTotal = Math.floor(dTotal); //7193
alert(dTotal + ' is after division');
dTotal = dTotal / 365.25;
dTotal = Math.floor(dTotal);
alert(dTotal + ' is how old you are!');
dTotal = birthYear - zodCycle;
dTotal = dTotal % chineseZod;
alert(dTotal);
alert(d);
var testS;
testS = dCurrent - d;
testS = testS / milliDay;
testS = testS * 365.25;
document.write("<span style=\"color: red;\">" + 'Your birthday is ' + d.toDateString() + "</span>");
alert(testS);
```

Comment: Best practice is to write a little test for this: take three or more predefined birth dates and compare them with predefined results (http://www.timeanddate.com/date/duration.html). That would be much easier as using alerts and SO code reviews =)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually much easier than that. Once you have the two dates (their birthday and "now"), you simply do this:

```
var days = Math.floor((now - birthDate) / 86400000);
```

This is because in JavaScript, [`Date` objects](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9) hold time in milliseconds since The Epoch and when you do math on them, they use that milliseconds value (and the result is a number of milliseconds). And JavaScript assumes exactly 86,400,000 milliseconds per day.

So once you have `birthYear`, `monthNum`, and `birthDay`:

```
var birthDate = new Date(birthYear, monthNum, birthDay);
var days = Math.floor((new Date() - birthdate) / 86400000);
```

[Live example using a datepicker](http://jsbin.com/uluwak) | [source](http://jsbin.com/uluwak/edit)

Comment: That works, but I also need to 'convert' the value to an integer and write it in blue as "You have been alive for x days". I forget how to convert to integers with js.

Comment: @Chara: The value is already a whole number (JavaScript doesn't have integers except internally; all numbers are floating-point), that's why I used `Math.floor`. I just added a full example to the answer, that should help.

Comment: The force is strong with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how exactly to implement this in JavaScript, but why don't you generate a timestamp based on the user's birth-date, subtract it from the current timestamp, and then (assuming the timestamp is in seconds) divide it by the number of seconds in a day?